# PHP SimpleXML raw content of node

Tags: php, simplexml

I am using PHP SimpleXML to parse data in a file.  Say for example I have the following XML content:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root>
  <parent1>
    <child1>blah</child1>
    <child2>blah blah</child2>
  </parent1>
  <parent2>blah</parent2>
</root>
```

I basically want to get the actual raw content of the inside of a node. I.e. I need it to return the "innerXML" of parent1 just as text, tags and all. Having trouble getting PHP to do this. Help?

Comment: Including  open `<parent>` and close tags ?

Comment: whats happen? why delete answer?

Comment: I don't save answers with negative rating

Answer (score 0):

For getting the exact content '`<child1>blah</child1><child2>blah blah</child2>`' as itself you better put them under `<![CDATA[]]>` Then you can get any thing inside that as iself.

xml should be like this::

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root>
  <parent1>
    <![CDATA[<child1>blah</child1>
    <child2>blah blah</child2>]]>
  </parent1>
  <parent2>blah</parent2>
</root>
```

Then

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);

$parent1 = $xml->parent1->asXml();
echo "<pre>";echo ($parent1);echo "<pre>";
```

This will output :

```
<child1>blah</child1>
<child2>blah blah</child2>
```